# How can I remove the minimum vertical padding or minimum height of a List row in SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, xcode, list, swiftui

I am trying to add a very short row to my list with a frame height of 2 but the list is adding an undesired padding above and below the list item or constraining to a minimum height and I don't know how to remove it.  I have produced the following to illustrate the problem:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        List {
            Color.red
                .frame(height: 2)
            Color.blue
                .frame(height: 2)
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

How can I remove this padding above and below the list item?  It's the same if using a section and adding header or footer.  It will not allow me to have a list entry with small frame height.

In a LazyVStack I don't have this problem but I need to use a list.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Use `.environment(\.defaultMinListRowHeight, 0)` to make each row have a minimum height of 0. Otherwise, each row will *always* be at least 44 (the default) points high.
2. Use `.listRowInsets(EdgeInsets())` to make each row have no inset. You could also do `.listRowInsets(EdgeInsets(top: 0, leading: 0, bottom: 0, trailing: 0))`, which results in the same.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        List {
            Color.red
                .frame(height: 5)
                .listRowInsets(EdgeInsets()) /// 2.
            Color.blue
                .frame(height: 5)
                .listRowInsets(EdgeInsets())
        }
        .environment(\.defaultMinListRowHeight, 0) /// 1.
    }
}
```

Result:

[image: Blue and red lines stacked vertically, with no gap in between]